# assigning a number vs generalized escape sequence in char or wchar_t to get symbol (too big for char)

Tags: c++

Why can I assign a large decimal number in a `char` or `wchar_t` and produce a symbol, but attempting to put it in the format of a generalized escape sequence produces the compiler error `"1824 too big for char"` Internally they should represent the same value/symbol no?

Example:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    wchar_t c = '\x720';
    wchar_t d = 1824;

    return 0;
}
```

That code produces `C022 error` because of `wchar_t c = '\x720';`. below is the table I'm using for reference.

[image: text]

Answer (score 1):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape hex escape sequences `\x` may only have 2 hex digits and results in 1 arbitrary byte.  You're probably looking to use a unicode escape sequence `\u` or `\U`, specifically `'\u0720'`.  Unicode escapes refer to specific unicode codepoints.  `\u` allows 4 hex digits for selecting from the Basic Multilingual Plane, and `\U` allows for up to 8 hex digits for selecting any unicode character.

Also, as noted by [Remy Lebeau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65863/remy-lebeau), `''` creates a `char`, which only holds values 0-127 safely. You need a `L` prefix to create a `wchar_t`:  `L'\u720'`.

Comment: c++ primer says that your statement is using octal, but it produces the same as x270 should. Now I'm even more confused. :S

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 only integer literals that start with a `0` are interpreted as octal.  The above sequence can not interpreted as an integer literal, it is a character (starts with `'`) and contains a Unicode escaped literal see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal

Comment: In your comment you said that escape sequences can only have 2 hex digits, but then you showed '\u0720' which is hex and has a value of 1824. Also, are hex values in unicode always written in this format? Lastly, L'\u0720' is 1824, but '\u0720' is 63, do you know why?

Comment: @Spellbinder2050: I've clarified my answer, but `\x` is for a hex escape (2 hex digits) , `\u` for a Unicode escape of the basic multilingual plane (4 hex digits), and `\U` for any Unicode character (8 hex digits).

Answer (score 1):

A `wchar_t` is 2 bytes on Windows, and 4 bytes on other platforms.  Either way, `1824` is not too large for a `wchar_t` on any platforms.

But `'\x720'` is not a `wchar_t` literal, it is a `char` literal, and `char` is only 1 byte on all platforms, so `1824` is indeed too large for a `char`.

Prefix `'\x720'` with `L` to make it a `wchar_t` literal, then it will fit:

```cpp
wchar_t c = L'\x720';
```

Comment: wchar_t d = L'x720'; gives me a value of 120, which is 'x'

Comment: @Spellbinder2050 You left out the ```\``` before the `x` -  `L'x720'` and `L'\x720'` are two completely different things.